# Facebook group members without profile link?

Tags: facebook

In the members list of a Facebook group I manage, some members are listed without a link to their profile (name only). What does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

They are unavailable.
If you use a computer log into your Facebook account.
Go to members on the left and click. Down the middle there should be a list of every member starting from admin/mods etc. On the right you should see a list that says unavailable. You will find there name in there. We delete the ones that we can. Some won’t let you.

Comment: Did that work for you?